# Hive Metastore column width limit

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, emr, metastore

Using **AWS EMR on the 5.2.1 version** as data processing environment, when dealing with a huge JSON file that has a complex schema with many nested fields, Hive can't process it and errors as it reaches the current limit of 4000 characters column length.

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   InvalidObjectException(message:Invalid column type name is too long: [...]

Looking at the documentation, there's already many issues regarding this problem or similar, though all unresolved [[1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12274), [2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1364)]. In this it is recommended to alter several fields of the Metastore to a different value in order to allow a greater length for struct definitions.

- `COLUMNS_V2.TYPE_NAME`
- `TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE`
- `SERDE_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE`
- `SD_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE`

As stated in the first issue, the proposed solution mentions:

> [...] after setting the values, the Metastore must also be *configured* and *restarted*."

Yet it is nowhere specified what must be *also* configured beside the DB values.

Thus, after updating the fields the current local Metastore (mysql in this case) from `string` to `mediumtext` and restarting the Metastore process, still can not get any progress as attempting to load the JSON continues to fail with same error.

Am I missing something or has anyone found an alternative workaround to overcome this problem?

Comment: did you find any solution to this ? having exactly the same issue

Comment: I think it is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15249

Comment: @GauravShah, still no luck, already tried in a locally w/ Hadoop & Hive (_local mysql Metastore_). I'm gonna try with the _embedded_ Derby database instead.

Comment: did you look at the issue , seems very relavant

Comment: it was added in hive 2.1 so very likely all the comments from other issues have not covered it

Comment: Yes! It seems that the issue you mention is indeed related. From what I understand, regardless of what you set in the Metastore columns, there is also a check for column type name set to 2000 characters that leads to the error we encounter.

Comment: you can go back to hive 1.x, and update column types. works for me

Comment: Just came accross this as well. Using it on aws emr-5.4.0 which has hive-2.1.1. The issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15249 is resolved and the fix is in hive-2.3.0 and 3.0.0. So this could work with emr-5.10.0, which has Hive-2.3.1 (can't confirm it yet, as i haven't tested it yet.)

Comment: Just want to confirm: Yes, emr-5.10.0 can do it! Tested with an avro schema with a bit more than 28000 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the MetaStore source code as the [Hive issue HIVE-15249](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15249) relates, there is also an additional check that applies beside the parameter constraints set in the MetaStore tables.

Particularly, in the `HiveMetaStoreUtils.java` file, the following declaration seems to be cause of the execution error:

```
public static final int MAX_MS_TYPENAME_LENGTH = 2000; // 4000/2, for an unlikely unicode case
```

Thus, changing the values for the mentioned in the MetaStore is not enough as the code constraint will throw the exception.